# C++ function with template template argument fail template argument deduction/substitution

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to write a generalized power set function for C++ STL containers using a template template argument.  The problem boils down to the following template argument deduction/substitution failing:

```
template <typename T, template<typename> class C>
C<C<T>> getPowerSet(typename C<T>::iterator begin, typename C<T>::iterator end)
...
vector<vector<int>> powerSet = getPowerSet<int, vector>(set.begin(), set.end());
```

Code and compiler error (using g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 20130531 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1)) follow.  I commented out parts unrelated to the compiler error.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, template<typename> class C>
C<C<T>> getPowerSet(typename C<T>::iterator begin, typename C<T>::iterator end)
{
    C<C<T>> powerSet;
    /*
    if (begin == end)
        return powerSet;

    C<C<T>> subproblem = getPowerSet(begin + 1, end);
    copy(subproblem.begin(), subproblem.end(), inserter(powerSet, powerSet.end()));
    for (C<T> set : subproblem)
    {
        *inserter(set, set.begin()) = *begin;
    }
    copy(subproblem.begin(), subproblem.end(), inserter(powerSet, powerSet.end()));
    */
    return powerSet;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> set;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        set.push_back(i);
    vector<vector<int>> powerSet = getPowerSet<int, vector>(set.begin(), set.end());
    /*
    for (auto set : powerSet)
    {
        for (int elem : set)
        {
            cout << elem << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    */
}
```

Below is the compiler error:

```
[thomas.bao@cwdev01 recursion]$ g++ 3.cpp
3.cpp:8:15: error: template argument 1 is invalid
 C<typename C<T>> getPowerSet(typename C<T>::iterator begin, typename C<T>::iterator end)
               ^
3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
3.cpp:31:83: error: no matching function for call to ‘getPowerSet(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator)’
     vector<vector<int>> powerSet = getPowerSet<int, vector>(set.begin(), set.end());
                                                                                   ^
3.cpp:31:83: note: candidate is:
3.cpp:8:18: note: template<class T, template<class> class C> int getPowerSet(typename C<T>::iterator, typename C<T>::iterator)
 C<typename C<T>> getPowerSet(typename C<T>::iterator begin, typename C<T>::iterator end)
                  ^
3.cpp:8:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

Comment: @Praetorian Note that C and T are explicitly specified in the function call.

Comment: @jrok Yep, didn't read the question carefully, only looked at the function signature

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16925220/1277769) may answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the signature to take a template argument with variadic parameter list

```
template <typename T, template<typename...> class C>
//                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
C<C<T>> getPowerSet(typename C<T>::iterator begin, typename C<T>::iterator end)
```

you don't need to add the allocator type to the call anymore.

Answer (score 1):

friend e-mailed me the following gem (damn you default template argument):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, typename S, template<typename, typename> class C>
C<C<T, S>, std::allocator<C<T, S> > > getPowerSet(typename C<T, S>::iterator begin, typename C<T, S>::iterator end)
{
  C<C<T, S>, std::allocator<C<T, S> > > powerSet;
    /*
    if (begin == end)
        return powerSet;

    C<C<T>> subproblem = getPowerSet(begin + 1, end);
    copy(subproblem.begin(), subproblem.end(), inserter(powerSet, powerSet.end()));
    for (C<T> set : subproblem)
    {
        *inserter(set, set.begin()) = *begin;
    }
    copy(subproblem.begin(), subproblem.end(), inserter(powerSet, powerSet.end()));
    */
    return powerSet;
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> set;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        set.push_back(i);
    auto powerSet = getPowerSet<int, std::allocator<int>, vector>(set.begin(), set.end());
    /*
    for (auto set : powerSet)
    {
        for (int elem : set)
        {
            cout << elem << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    */
}
```