# Class template with variable type of container

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I would like to know if it's possible to create a class template with an object that has to be a container but of a kind specified by the user.

For example, now I have a class like this:

```
template<class T>
class Myclass {
    std::queue<T> queue;

    // SOME OTHER MEMBERS
}
```

But I would like to be able to make that `std::queue` object some other type of container when needed, like a `std:stack`, in order to be able to handle also containers with other kind of policies other than FIFO.

Is it possible? Or are there any other solutions that don't involve me creating another class exactly like this but with a `stack` instead of a `queue`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use std::vector as a template parameter or does it need to be std::vector<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925041/can-i-use-stdvector-as-a-template-parameter-or-does-it-need-to-be-stdvector)

Comment: @Rakete1111 I don't think this question is a duplicate of the question that has been proposed. In the other question they already know how to make a variable type container, here I don't.

Comment: Well, I think they are still fairly similar. The answers are equivalent too, so I thought that it was a dupe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can.  This is called a container adapter.  `std::queue` itself is a container adapter and looks like

```
template<class T, class Container = std::deque<T>> 
class queue
{
    //...
};
```

Doing that though requires you to use something like

```
std::queue<int, std::vector<int>> foo;
```

If you want to change the container.  If you do not want to have to specify the template type of the container then you can use a template template like

```
template<class T, template<typename...> class Container = std::queue> 
class Myclass
{
    Container<T> cont;
};
```

and you can use it like

```
Myclass<int, std::set> foo;
```

To change it to use a `std::set` instead of the default `std::queue`.

Comment: So if I use it like this: `Myclass<int> foo;` it will use a `std::queue` as the default container, while if I explicitly declare it it will use the type of container I specify, right? And may I ask what the `...` in `typename...` are for? I've never seen that syntax

Comment: Correct.  The `...` makes it a variadic template which means it can take any amount of template types.  This is useful here since different containers have different amounts of template parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I'm starting to understand templates and they are something awesome! Thank you again

Comment: @jackscorrow That they are.  You can do a lot of cool things with them.