# C++ factory of a container type without defining the container element type

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, factory-pattern, abstraction

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44572705/class-template-with-variable-type-of-container) topic, I wonder if it would be possible to have a factory class that would provide a container type, without defining the type of element of the container.

Something like:

```
template <typename t_container>
class factory {
public:
  using container = t_container;
}
```

so that *something like* this, but not exactly with this syntax because I know it is not valid in C++, would work:

```
...
factory<std::vector>::container<int> my_container;
...
```

The idea is that `factory` would define the type of container, but not the type of element that `factory::container` would contain, leaving that decision to the user code.

Comment: Are you looking for template-template parameters perhaps? Something like https://godbolt.org/z/Pf5vh6TM9? But you can't have the `using` like you've written.

Comment: @cigien [Why not?](https://godbolt.org/z/Ycxq443j7)

Comment: @WeijunZhou For the exact reason why you've had to make the `using` an alias template. As the OP has written it, it's not possible, because `t_container` would not be a type at all (it would have be a template) as shown in the demo I linked.

Comment: OK. I think I misunderstood what you meant to be impossible.

Comment: fwiw, `factory` is typically what we call the thing that creates something. If you want it to be merely "some template where the user specifies the element type" i would give it a different name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `t_container` to be a template, hence `template <typename t_container>` is wrong (it declares `t_container` to be a type, but `std::vector` is not a type). And after fixing that, your `using` declaration isnt right, because it assumes `t_container` is a type.

You can do that by using a template template argument:

```
#include <vector>


template <template <typename...> class C>
struct factory {
    template <typename T>
    using container = C<T>;

    template <typename T> 
    container<T> make() { return C<T>{};}

};


int main ()
{
   auto vec_int = factory<std::vector>{}.make<int>();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G1xvdE7fo)

The same `factory<std::vector>` can make vectors with different element type as illustrated by the member alias template and member function template.

There is only one small issue, when using container with non-type template arguments. The above will not work for `std::array`, because its 2nd argument is a `size_t` not a type. Also eg `std::map` is not covered by the above, because its element type is specified by 2 parameter (key and value type).

Comment: Very fine solution, but I need 'vec_int' to be an attribute of a class. 'factory' would be a type supplier rather than an object creator.

Comment: @canellas and? You can remove the method if you do not need it

Comment: @canellas the `factory<std::vector>::container<int> my_container;` you ask for is there. Not sure why you think "but I need 'vec_int' to be an attribute of a class" would be a problem

Comment: You are correct, your solution is what I need. Thanks a lot!