# error: no matching function for call to ‘recherche(std::vector >&, std::vector >::iterator, std::vector >::iterator, const char [10])’

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector

I got these errors:

**error: no matching function for call to ‘recherche(std::vector >&, std::vector >::iterator, std::vector >::iterator, const char [10])’**

**error: no matching function for call to ‘recherche(std::__cxx11::list&, std::__cxx11::list::iterator, std::__cxx11::list::iterator, int)’**

**error: no matching function for call to ‘recherche(std::array&, std::array::iterator, std::array::iterator, double)’**

here is my code

```cpp
template <template<typename> class C, class InputIterator, typename A>
bool recherche(C<A> s, InputIterator debut, InputIterator fin, A n)
{
    InputIterator itr;
    for (itr = debut; itr != fin; itr++) {
        if(*itr == n){
            return 1;
        }}
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    vector<string> strVec = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
    list<int> my_list = { 12, 5, 10, 9, 4, 90 };
    array<float, 5> arr = { 10.56, 20.99, 30.34, 40.12, 10.1 };
    
    cout << recherche(strVec, strVec.begin(), strVec.end(), "Wednesday") << endl;
    cout << recherche(my_list, my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), 90) << endl;
    cout << recherche(arr, arr.begin(), arr.end(), 30.34) << endl;
    
    return 0;
    }
}
```

thank you so much for your help
I fix them with this template

```cpp
template<class Container, class InputIterator, typename T>
bool recherche(Container& cont, InputIterator debut, InputIterator fin, T n)
{
    InputIterator itr;
    for (itr = debut; itr != fin; itr++)
    {
        if (*itr == n)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it's work fine

Comment: Check out the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16925041/can-i-use-stdvector-as-a-template-parameter-or-does-it-need-to-be-stdvector . Also `std::vector` is a template with two template parameter types, not one, so that might be the reason you get the error

Comment: Another thing that will bite you: You search for `30.34` which makes `A` a `double`. It will not be equal to the `30.34f` that you store in `arr`

Comment: It is useless to pass both the container and iterators to your `recherche` function.

Comment: Your `recherche()` function is replicating what the standard `std::find()` algorithm already does. There is little benefit to writing your own function when a standard algorithm can do the same job. `template <class InputIterator, class T> bool recherche(InputIterator debut, InputIterator fin, T n) { return std::find(debut, fin, n) != fin; }`

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` takes two template parameters, one for the element and one for the allocator. One way to solve this would be to accept them both in the function:

```cpp
template <template<typename, typename> class C, class InputIterator, typename Elem, typename Alloc>
bool recherche(C<Elem, Alloc> s, InputIterator debut, InputIterator fin, Elem n)
{
    InputIterator itr;
    for (itr = debut; itr != fin; itr++) {
        if(*itr == n){
            return 1;
        }}
    return 0;
}
```

However you can also get the element value type by taking advantage of `value_type` that all STL containers implement:

```cpp
template<class Vec, class Elem = Vec::value_type>
void foo(Vec v, Elem e) {
    // the element type is extracted in compile time. The only constraint is
    // that your container must implement value_type and all stl containers do so
    // Of course Vec is not necessarily a vector, it can be a list, an array, an unordered_map etc.
}
```

Comment: You should be able to omit the `Alloc` parameter in C++11 and later: `template <template<typename...> class C, class InputIterator, typename Elem> bool recherche(C<Elem> s, InputIterator debut, InputIterator fin, Elem n)`